# The sin in a fundamental System of Solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wan't to get the real solutions of the ODE $y^{(4)}-81y=0$. The characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^4=81$ and therefore the eigenvalues are $\lambda_i=3, -3, 3i, -3i$. The fundamental system of solutions should be $\{e^{3x}, e^{-3x}, \cos(3x), \sin(3x)\}$. Is it right, that $\cos(3x)$ is in the fundamental system, because it is the real part of $e^{3ix}=\cos(3x)+i\sin(3x)$ and $\sin(3x)$, because it is the imaginary part.

My question is, why $\Re(e^{\lambda x})$ and $\Im(e^{\lambda x})$ are basis vectors of the space of Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Since some of the eigenvalues are complex, that is $\lambda_i = u \pm iv$. Then you must seek a solution of the form: $y(x) = C_1e^u cos(vx) + C_2 e^u sin(vx)$. In you case you must add $C_3e^{3x} + C_4e^{-3x}$ and notice that $ u = 0 \wedge v = 3$.